# Why won't icon display when I click on my SettingsActivity?

Tags: android

I have a basic SettingsActivity for my android app in the right corner of my action bar. When you click on the three ellipses, the menu will pop up with the different selections (activities) that you can go to.

So far I have:
About and Settings

The menu looks pretty plain, so I'd like to add an icon next to each of these words.

I've tried:

```
<item
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Unfortunately, the icon does not show up next to my two options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<item
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/about"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I've already tried switching the action to always. Now both icons display right on the action bar. I only want them to display next to my menu items when I tap the ellipses.